# Finding a string between two substrings in arabic

Tags: python, string

I have a string

```
string = "الطالب يذهب الي الممدرسة"
```

I want to extract
`يذهب`
I have tried  the following code:

```
import re
res = re.search('الي(.*)الطالب', string)
print(res.group(1))
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching the order of the substrings surrounding `(.*)` solves the problem:

```
string = "الطالب يذهب الي الممدرسة"

import re
res = re.search('الطالب(.*)الي', string)
print(res.group(1))
```

Output: `' يذهب '`

(I suspect you simply misentered the regular expression due to the way bidirectional text is displayed on your system.)

If the letters are displayed in their isolated forms, with logical ordering **from left to right** (that is, in the same order as the surrounding Python code), the original (faulty) string would be this

[image: faulty regex string]

and the corrected string would be this

[image: corrected regex string]

Comment: Thanks a lot. But is there is another easier solution than re.search ?

Comment: I think this is the easiest I can think of, for the problem of extracting a substring flanked by two specific strings on the left and on the right. If you have a more general problem, perhaps there is a more general solution (and you can certainly ask about that on this site), but I suspect the solution would need to be more complicated.

Comment: The problem is that I follow this method on other arabic text and sometimes it doesnt work and give me this error : error: nothing to repeat at position 7

Comment: See my edit: Actually the output has spaces around the string. I am not sure whether this is related to your issue (`.` does match spaces). For further debugging, you need to supply more examples.

Comment: Here is an example where I want to extract علي محمد علي but it give me the nothing to repeat error : test=' علي محمد علي  كان * * # # # # # # # «'

res = re.search("كان(*.)* *", test)
print(res.group(1))

Comment: Here "كان" is logically at the *end* of your Arabic text within the test string, and in the regex, you need to change `(.) *` to `(.*)`. I suggest downloading an editor like BabelPad whose "simple rendering" option lets you display Arabic text in left-to-right order, for debugging purposes. With a regex like `(.*)كان`, things work correctly.